# Filtering products by category id

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Vue.js component and I have products displayed by this component. I would like to filter products by selected category in a computed section. I have already created a filterdProducts function but it returns all the products not only products with selected category id.
In this case I would expecting to filterdProducts returns to me products with category id 9 but it returns all my products.
Related categories are nested inside product.
for example

[image]

{

```
export default {
data(){
    return{
       selectedcategory: 9,
    }
},
```

and here ismay code for filtering:

```
computed:{
filteredProducts: function () {
    return this.products.filter((product) => {
        return product.categories.filter((category) => { 
            return category.id === this.selectedCategory; 
         });
        })
    }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake

```
export default {
 data(){
  return{
   selectedcategory: 9,
 }
},
```

Should be selectedCategory